# Using checkbox as gridview control

Tags: vb.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a gridview that uses a stored procedure for its select statement. The stored proecedure accepts a varchar and a bit. I want a checkbox outside of the gridview to change the value of the bit. I've set the parameter to the checkbox but it doesn't seem to be working. Am I missing something?

Comment: Perhaps a code snippet and a little more preamble would help. Is there a checkbox outside th gridview that changes the bit for all rows in the selected data?

Comment: The stored proecedure the gridview is using as a select statement returns different rows depending on if the bit is true or not. The checkbox I want the gridview to use for the bit parameter is outside the gridview. What code would you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was another error in the query. Default settings for checkboxing mapped as a control to a gridview work as expected, returning true/false.